# SAPUI5 - property scope

Tags: sapui5

I have two controls, one that extends from Control, and one that extends from my custom control.

The controls have an array property that I want to be unique per instance:

```
/* parent control */
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("foo.MyControl", {
    metadata: {
        properties: {
            name: { type: 'string' },
            myArray: { type: 'array', defaultValue: [] }
        }
    },
    renderer: {
        render: function( oRenderManager, oControl ) {
            oRenderManager.write('<div>My name is: ' + oControl.getName() + '</div>');
        }
    }
});

/* child control */
foo.MyControl.extend("foo.MyChildControl", {
    renderer: {
        render: foo.MyControl.prototype.render
    }
});
```

And then I create instances of them and place them in the dom:

```
/* create and place instances */
var oMyControl = new foo.MyControl({
        name: 'parent control'
    }),
    oMyChildControl = new foo.MyChildControl({
        name: 'child control'
    });
oMyControl.placeAt('uiArea');
oMyChildControl.placeAt('uiArea');
```

Why are the 2 array instances equal?

```
alert(oMyControl.getMyArray() === oMyChildControl.getMyArray()); // true
```

I would expect that each instance would get it's own array.

**

### TL;DR For defining control metadata, declare array properties as type "object"

**

Comment: you may be missing code in your example, as it reads oMyControl.getMyArray() === [] && oMyChildControl.getMyArray() === [], ([] === []) true

Comment: If I populate oMyControl.getMyArray() it also populates oMyChildControl.getMyArray() because they are sharing the same reference which is what I am confused about. I want them to have their own array instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got exceptions when trying to run your code

type: 'array' isn't correct

> The typeof operator in JavaScript returns "object" for arrays.

this works for me

```
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("foo.MyControl", {
    metadata: {
        properties: {
            name: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            myArray: {
                type: 'object',
                defaultValue: []
            }
        }
    },
    renderer: {
        render: function(oRenderManager, oControl) {
            oRenderManager.write('<div>' + oControl.getMyArray().toString() + '</div>');
        }
    }
});

/* child control */
foo.MyControl.extend("foo.MyChildControl", {
    renderer: {
        render: foo.MyControl.prototype.render
    }
});

/* create and place instances */
var oMyControl = new foo.MyControl({
    name: 'parent control'
}).placeAt('content');

var oMyChildControl = new foo.MyChildControl({
        name: 'child control'
}).placeAt('content');

var aFruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var aColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green"];
oMyControl.setMyArray(aFruits);
oMyChildControl.setMyArray(aColors);
```